# Check for the user input isValid

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js and knockout.validation. I created a book view model which contain
2 properties for book author name and book name :

```
function BookViewModel(bookObject) {
        var self = this;
        self.AuthorName = ko.observable(bookObject.AuthorName)
            .extend({
                required: { message: "Please enter menu name" },
                minLength: 4,
                maxLength: 10
            });
        self.Name = ko.observable(bookObject.Name)
            .extend({
                required: { message: "Please enter course name" },
                minLength: 4,
                maxLength: 10
            });
}
```

I have applied native validation rules on the properties. Now i know that we can check wheteher the property value is valid or not by :

```
     bookViewModelObject.AuthorName.isValid()
```

Now by the help of above statement we can check whether the user`s entered author name satisfy our validation rules. My question is how can i check whether all the properties of bookViewModel is valid or not, in a single statement ? Means something like this :

```
     bookViewModelObject.isValid()
```

Comment: You can create a computed property for it.

Comment: @YograjGupta thanks for response but can you please give a short example code for what you suggested ?

Comment: like self.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.AuthorName.isValid() && self.Name.isValid()
    }, self);

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ko.validation.group`:

```
var viewModel = new BookViewModel(data);
viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(viewModel);
```

In `viewModel.errors` you will have number of errors in `viewModel`.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/3J3qV/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this worked before but now (with KnockoutJS 3.0 and validation plugin 2.1) you can do just that ie.

```
ko.validation.init();
var validatedViewModel = ko.validatedObservable(new BookViewModel(book))();
ko.applyBindings(validatedViewModel);

validatedViewModel.isValid();
```

Notice the `ko.validatedObservable()` method.

Here is the apropriate [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LGyT6/1/).